# Cannot raise/throw exception inside CATCH block SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, try-catch, throw, raiserror

I need to throw/raise an exception in SQL to catch in C# application. However, whenever I throw an error inside CATCH block the error is not actually thrown.
Here is the SQL code I am using:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        INSERT INTO Transactions (Id, Amount) 
        VALUES (NEWID(), 43346);

        INSERT INTO Transactions (Id, Amount) 
        VALUES (NEWID(), 'fas');
    COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

--  RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);

    THROW 50001,  @ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity;
END CATCH;
```

I tried both `THROW` and `RAISERROR` methods. However, none of them works. I tested it in my app and in DBeaver but I still cannot raise an exception. Moreover, when I raise an exception outside of `CATCH` block, then the exception is raised using both `THROW` and `RAISERROR`methods. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What are the data types of (Id, Amount) columns?

Comment: Guid, and decimal(6, 2). I especially tried to insert string instead of int in order to raise an exception and enter CATCH block section

Comment: if you use just throw; it will rethrow the original error....and the last parameter to throw is state and not severity.

Comment: yeah, my fault, I accidentally put `@ErrorSeverity` instead of `@ErrorState`. However, when I use just `THROW` it is still doesn't work. I thought the `ROLLBACK` command is going to also discard the error.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table? The only thing that comes to mind is a trigger is returning results which is interfering with the client recognizing the error.

Comment: No, I don't have any triggers. The weird thing which I don't quite understand is that the error is being raised if it is outside of `CATCH` block. I don't quite get it why it behaves like that

Comment: I inherited some SQL code that is written this way, and can't figure out why it doesn't actually do what you might think it would do. In searching around, every author / tutorial I came across defines the THROW statement like this: Raises an exception and transfers execution to a CATCH block of a TRY...CATCH construct. My conclusion is that it was never supposed to be used inside the CATCH block. In debug mode it will generate the message you specified, but then it just continues execution after the CATCH block terminates. Not very useful if you want the program to terminate on error...